# How to use a multi value converter for a field in xamdatagrid?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I want to convert a list to comma separated string. For that purpose I am using multivalue converter.
But I dont know how to bind it to a field in xamdatagrid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this work for you?

```
      <igDP:Field Name="Property"">
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings>
                            <igDP:FieldSetting.CellValuePresenter>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="DataItem.Property1" />
                                                <Binding Path="DataItem.Property2" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </igDP:FieldSetting.CellValuePresenter>
                        </igDP:FieldSettings>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
```

I'm not so sure property "Content" works, but I can't test it right now, If it is not you can just define a template inside you CellValuePresenter and bind the converter to a textbox or any other control you want to use

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks alot, I shouldn't use Multivalue coverter for comma separated string. But your code helps me in getting that.